# Loop to conditionally format cells in ranges over multiple worksheets

Tags: vba, loops, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to conditionally format cells across multiple worksheets. The size of range varies per sheet (and possibly month-to-month). Each sheet will have a header and the number of columns will be different, but the data to be formatted will always start at A6.

I successfully selected the last cell on each sheet and I successfully formatted a few cells on each worksheet. However, when I try to combine the steps I am unsuccessful.

```
Sub comfor()
Dim ws As Worksheet, LstR As Range
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
  Set LstR = ws.Range("A6").SpecialCells(xlLastCell)
       For Each cell In LstR
         If cell.Text = "Complete" Then
            cell.Font.Color = 5287936
            cell.Replace What:="Complete", Replacement:="R"
            cell.Font.Name = "Wingdings 2"
        End If
        Next cell
  Next ws
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (untested)

```
Sub comfor()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, cell As Range

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

       For Each cell In ws.range(ws.range("A6"), _
                                 ws.Range("A6").SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).cells
           With cell  
               If .Text = "Complete" Then
                   .Font.Color = 5287936
                   .Value ="R"
                   .Font.Name = "Wingdings 2"
               End If
           End with

        Next cell
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you! I'm curious why "With cell" instead of "For each"?

Comment: There are both "For Each" and "With".  `With` is a little bit more efficient than repeating `cell` on each of those lines.